# Find inverse of a continuous map in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: functions, continuity, inverse-function

I need to show that the continuous map $H: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined by

$$H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}
\\ x_{2}+x_{1}^{2}
\\ x_{3} + \frac{1}{3}x_{1}^{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

has a continuous inverse. Now I am confused as how to approach this. I know in general $A\cdot A^{-1}=I$, but I do not see how I can apply this to this continuous system. 
 Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Comment: You can't work out the matrix inverse of a non-square matrix. Aren't they just asking you to show that the function $f(x,y,z)=(x,y+x^2,z+x^2/3)$ has a continuous inverse?

Comment: Matrix representation of $T\in\mathcal L(V)$ has to be a $\dim V\times\dim V$ square matrix since $V\cong V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1=y_1\\x_2+x_1^{\,2}=y_2\\x_3+\frac13x_1^{\,2}=y_3.\end{array}\right.$$You will get$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1=y_1\\x_2=-y_1^{\,2}+y_2\\x_3=-\frac13y_1^{\,2}+y_3.\end{array}\right.$$Therefore$$H^{-1}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(x_1,-x_1^{\,2}+x_2,-\frac13x_1^{\,2}+x_3\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, makes total sense. Appreciate it. I did not think of this simple change of variables.